# Html drop down linked to different web page

Tags: html

I am a newbie in html. My scenarios goes as below.
I have a drop down with values. My need is to navigate to respective webpage(which I have created for each values in the dropdown) on click/selection of one value.
Help me in achieving this.

Comment: Unfortunately, stack overflow is not a code generator, but you can use <select> and <option> tags to build your dropdown, then you can assign a javascript function in the "onchange" attribute in the select tag for going to a webpage based on the selected value. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

Comment: My need is to achieve this using HTML only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Javascript to change URL based on option selected in dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835998/using-javascript-to-change-url-based-on-option-selected-in-dropdown)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using href links inside <option> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000656/using-href-links-inside-option-tag)

Answer (score 1):

I think Javascript is needed for your case...

```html
<select onchange="document.location.href=this.value;">
  <option value="https://www.stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</option>
  <option value="https://www.google.com">Google</option>
  <option value="https://www.instagram.com">Instagram</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes using java script it cane be done. Is there a way we can achieve this using only HTML?